# jQuery on contextmenu, toggle on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-events

I recently used jQuery's `on('contextmenu'...`

But is it possible to toggle it on and off like jQuery's toggle functionality?

**E.G.**

```
$('#option').on('contextmenu', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

// on second click removeClass('selected');
```

I used the `contextmenu` event because I want a different behavior on just a `click` and a `rightclick`.

Was it possible to **toggle** it on and off like off that `toggle`?

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('selected')` ?

Comment: Did you try searching for this, like say ["toggle class with jQuery"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=toggle+class+with+jQuery) ??

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `.toggleClass`. I've also added `return false` to prevent the context menu from actually showing up, but that's for you to decide (remove it if you want the context menu):

http://jsfiddle.net/kjKZ3/

Another note: There's a typo in your question; you should be adding class `'selected'` and not class `'.selected'`.

Comment: uhmmm, how about doing other things aside from adding and removing classes...  like adding and removing value from an array?

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. Basically the same thing, but you provide two functions to toggle.